# How to find duplicate lines recursivly in folder with ubuntu commandline?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find duplicate lines (right after each other) recursivly in a folder and it's subfolders. Using a ubuntu command line.

I was using commands like:

```
sudo grep -liRZP --color '(src\=\"https\:\/\/).*(\/wp-content\/.*\.png\")' --exclude=\*{.sql,_log,.log,backup*,.*backup*,Backup*,.*Backup*,BACKUP*,.*BACKUP*,.png} . | xargs -0 sed -i[backup] -e 's_\(src\=\"\)https\:\/\/.*\(\/wp-content\/.*\.png\"\)_\1\2_gp'
```

in the recent past, but in the beginning I must have made mistakes. Therefore I now discovered that I have many files that show douplicate lines. For example they look like this:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.get_permalink(2320).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/info.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Information & FAQ</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.get_permalink(2320).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/info.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Information & FAQ</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "overview")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/preview.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Overview<$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "overview")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/preview.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Overview<$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "sales")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sale.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Sales</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "sales")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sale.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Sales</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "impressions")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/impression.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Imp$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "impressions")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/impression.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Imp$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "payments")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/payment-history.png" class="menu-icon"></span>P$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "payments")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/payment-history.png" class="menu-icon"></span>P$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "creatives")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/promotion.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Promot$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "creatives")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/promotion.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Promot$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "profile")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/edit-pro.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Edit Prof$
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.getLinkab(array("sub" => "profile")).'"><span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/edit-pro.png" class="menu-icon"></span>Edit Prof$
```

In a first step I want to see a list of affected lines. And in a second step I would like to delete the douplicate lines.

I have tried to use:

```
sudo grep -iRE --color '\(^.*$\)\1' .
```

but that throws an error:

```
grep: Invalid back reference
```

I also tried:

```
sudo grep -iRP --color '\(^.*$\)\1'
```

The error:

```
grep: reference to non-existent subpattern
```

Can anybody help me? How to best delete the duplicate lines?

Comment: See `uniq` for one option, if the full lines are repeated.

Comment: But how to use `uniq` recursivly for my case?

Comment: I'd `shopt -s globstar` and then use `**/*.html` (or whatever pattern seems appropriate). But the traditional way would be based on `find . -name '*.html' -type f -print0 | xargs -0`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have never worked with `shopt` before but from what I can read [Shopt Tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) I don't see how this can help me here? Can you explain?
I am currently thinking it was `grep ... xargs .... sed` that made the "mess" (of course it was me ;-( ) so it should be the same to repair it again.

Comment: I don't know what all that grepping etc. does. But I can tell you what `**/*.html` does: it gives you the paths to all files (recursively) with extension `.html`. Perhaps that's not what you need; maybe there are more extensions. But it seemed like a good first cut.

Comment: It's always best if you can arrange for a bulk modification command to be idempotent. For deduplicating lines, that should be almost automatic since a deduplicator shouldn't affect a file without duplicates. If the modification is not idempotent, you need to watch out for symlinjs because they can cause a single file to have two different names. That might be how you got into trouble in the first place. `find` has some useful options.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment about symlinks. I guess you are right here. Regarding the other information unfortunately it currently does not sum up to a solution for me as my knowladge is too limited at this point. I'll try to explore it further. In the meantime additional ideas are very welcome.

Comment: rici's comment about symlinks probably applies to hard links as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty identification of the files:

```
find . -type f | parallel --tag 'diff {} <(uniq {})'
```

Quick and dirty replacement:

```
find . -type f | parallel 'cp {} {}.old; cat {}.old | uniq > {}'
```

Only look at lines > 10 char and containing the string 'a href':

```
myuniq() {
  perl -ne 'if($last eq $_ and /a href/ and length($_) > 10) {
    # Dont print
    1;
  } else {
    print;
  }
  $last=$_;' "$@"
}
export -f myuniq

find . -type f | parallel --tag 'diff {} <(myuniq {})'
# cp the file first to conserve permissions
find . -type f | parallel 'cp -a {} {}.old; cat {}.old | myuniq > {}'
```

Comment: I have finetuned the solution a bit. However it still gives me many results that I don't need. Most (if not all) are very short. E.g. `*` `*` for two lins just containing a `*` . How can I tell the solution to output only lines with a certain length. E.g. minimum of 12 characters in one line?


`sudo find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -mtime -5 | parallel --tag 'diff -bBw {} <(uniq {})'`

Comment: Thanks. `"... to conserve permissions"` --> Good point! 1. Why did my first code `sudo grep -liRZP --color '(src\=\"https\:\/\/).*(\/wp-content\/.*\.png\")' --exclude=\*{.sql,.log,.png} . | xargs -0 sed -i[backup] -e 's_\(src\=\"\)https\:\/\/.*\(\/wp-content\/.*\.png\"\)_\1\2_gp'` made a backup file even of files that were not changed by `sed`? 2. Why does it behave different for ownership and modification date? (After execution I got e.g. (a) `picture.jpg` `old user:group` but `new modification date`. (b) `picture.jpg[backup]` `new group` but `old modification date`. Why? Both have same size.

Comment: 1. `sed` always makes a backup - whether or not it was changed. 2. Not sure.